# Windows 10 - multiple desktops, different resolutions, one monitor?

Tags: windows-10, display, resolution, multiple-desktop

Googling around has led me on a rather wild goose chase (particularly, lots of "multiple monitors" articles crop up).

So, I want to run multiple desktops on my laptop here - one for playing a low-res game that requires fullscreen, and one for the rest of the nonsense I might run.

The problem is, when I run the game in question, and switch desktops, the resolution "persists", and when I alter the resolution on one desktop, the other desktop resizes also.

How can I "desync" the resolutions between desktops for ease-of-use? I'll hazard a guess that some cmd or powershell shenanigans are needed, but I don't have the eldritch knowledge of all of Windows' modules.

Comment: Virtual Machines: That's perhaps the best/easiest answer.

Comment: o right and free windows 10 is still offered, might go that route if no answers crop up in a few weeks. Depends on the performance impact, tbf.

Comment: If the game is older, if you have not yet done so, you should do some research on how others play it on modern OSes. There may be specific methods others have found successful for this task.

Comment: Nah, every search I've done for a supposed fix has been sketchy third-party tools that made Windows Defender go more than ten shades of "reeeee". Suffice it to say, I think a Windows-focal method is more suitable.

Comment: Perhaps giving us the name of the game may help bring in answers.

Comment: It's TGM3:TI, it was designed for an environment alike Windows XP.